# Reading byte array Textbox -> byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, nemerle

I've got Textbox with a string like `89 3d 2c c0 7f 00`

How to store it to Byte[] (byte array) variable ?

Now I can read only one dec value :(

```
Value=BitConverter.GetBytes(Int32.Parse(this.textBox3.Text.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `textBox3.Text.Split()` to get an array of strings, each of length 2.

Then use `byte.Parse(part, NumberStyles.HexNumber)` in a loop to convert each part from hexadecimal to an integer.

Using LINQ it can be written like this:

```
byte[] result = textBox3.Text.Split(' ')
    .Select(part => byte.Parse(part, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I no need to convert to integer , I need bit :-/

Comment: I think the only reason the Parse was in the quesiton is because he's using the BitConvertor. He doesn't really want the values as Ints.